# Making custom UIView with two UIButtons for UITableViewCell accessoryView member causes unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: uitableview, uibutton, unrecognized-selector, accessoryview

I'm trying to make a view with two buttons for a table cell accessory view to do two (obviously) different things to the object at that cell index. I made two basic rounded rect UIButtons with a selector in the RootViewController (where the UITableView resides). Here is the code I use to initialize this view in a cell that is found in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

`UIButton* minus = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
[minus setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[minus setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[minus addTarget:self action:@selector(subtractOne:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIButton* plus = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
[plus setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 30, 30)];
[plus setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[plus addTarget:self action:@selector(addOne:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIView* customAccessory = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
[customAccessory addSubview:minus];
[customAccessory addSubview:plus];
cell.accessoryView = customAccessory;
[customAccessory release];`

And the two methods they call are defined:

`- (void)subtractOne:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)addOne:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

Any ideas why this would throw unrecognized sender sent to instance "RootViewController"?

Here is the full error:

2011-03-20 20:34:35.493 MyApp[23262:207] -[RootViewController subtractOne:event:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x573c350
2011-03-20 20:34:35.496 MyApp[23262:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController subtractOne:event:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x573c350'

Comment: Your code actually helped me to create a custom accessory view with two buttons. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Realized my own stupid mistake: Was trying to call on subtractOne:event: when I wrote method for subtractOne:forEvent: